Do Self Adjoint Matrices Always have an Orthonormal Basis?
I have a self-adjoint matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1+ i \\
1- i & 2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
It is self-adjoint because its transpose conjugate is identical to the original matrix.  I get the eigenvalues $0,3$.  I then get eigenvectors for $\lambda = 0,3$ respectively with their first entries $-1-i$ and $\frac{1+i}{2}$; with each second entry as $1$.
I then normalize by $(v_1\bar{v_1}+1)^{1/2}$ where $v_1$ is the first entry and the same for the other vector.
Then I use the formula $\langle u,v \rangle$ for these now normalized eigenvectors (divided by their respective norms) and it does not go to $0$. This makes me think I've made an error because I think that Gram-Schmidt is unnecessary in a self-adjoint matrix. Please help.

How can that be self adjoint?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

It's self adjoint because the transpose swaps entry 1,2 with 2,1; then you take the conjugate.  This is identical to the initial Matrix.

I'm asking which part I'm making a mistake it.

The eigenvectors you obtained are correct and are orthogonal to each other. You probably either made a mistake in the normalization process or in calculating the inner product. (I don’t know for sure since you didn’t write down your later calculation steps, but one possible source of errors: the inner product is not just the dot product, you have to take the complex conjugate of the first vector - or the second, depending on the convention you’re following.)

Normalization is a waste of time. Two vectors are orthogonal if and only if their normalizations are orthogonal.

I got the norms for the first eigenvector to be 3^.5 and the second eigenvector to be 6^.5, I then multiply correspond entries to which does not equal 0.

I'm sorry I don't understand the "normalization is a waste of time".  What's the difference between that and finding the unit vector? Then taking the inner product to see if it's 0?

@questionz Your norm calculation is not exactly right. But as Gerry mentioned, it doesn’t really matter anyway. If you’re not getting zero after a wrong normalization, you wouldn’t get zero with a correct normalization either. It sounds to me, based on your description, that you forget to take the complex conjugate of the first vector - again, inner product between complex vectors is not just the dot product, you need to take the complex conjugate of one of the vectors before multiplying the corresponding entries.

@questionz What Gerry meant was that, in order to verify orthogonality, normalization is unnecessary. $v$ and $w$ are orthogonal iff their normalizations are orthogonal. So if you take the inner product of $v$ and $w$ and it’s not zero, then their normalizations would have nonzero inner product as well, and vice versa.

Thank you for clarifying!!

Eigenvectors of self-adjoint matrices are always orthogonal. Your eigenvectors are orthogonal as follows.
Computing the dot product you need to take the conjugate of one of them, since this is the way the standard scalar product in unitary space is defined:
$$
\langle v,w\rangle =v^{T}\bar{w} =\begin{bmatrix} -1-i , 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1-i}{2} \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}=-\frac{1}{2}+ \frac{i}{2}-\frac{i}{2}- \frac{1}{2}+1\cdot 1=-1+1=0
$$
I hope this helps.

Thanks for spelling it out!
